# Save variable in pc python

Tags: python, python-3.x, save, store, savechanges

I want to save a variable (user input fo mail) in pc. Because I don't want it to ask to login again and again. So please help me with how to store email variable in pc and also how to access it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want exactly.

If you just wanna save a text(I mean, string) in variable, then write it to a file like this.

```py
f = open("some_file_to_save.txt", 'w')
f.write(your_variable)
f.close()
```

Or if you want data to be loaded as python variable again, then you can utilize [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html)

Answer (score 0):

May be you need config to your program?
So for this use the [configparser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html)

```
import configparser
```

You need 2 functions, first to Save:

```
def save_config(email):
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config['DEFAULT'] = {
        'Email': email
    }
    with open('config.ini', 'w') as configfile:
        config.write(configfile)
```

And second to read saved data:

```
def read_config():
    config = configparser.ConfigParser()
    config.read('config.ini')
    return config['DEFAULT']['Email']
```

Then add it to your code or use this example:

```
try:
    email = read_config()
except:
    print("Config doest contain email, type it:")
    email = input()
print(f"My email is {email}")
save_config(email)
```

Comment: Hello , Thanks for your answer , I know it's late reply but what is ini file? Can users easily read , write or create it?